# Constraint layout center vertically if place

Tags: android, layout, constraints

I center my two Input layout vertically in my view using chaining. I also have an image view and a text view on top of this two Input layout. I would like to have this Input Layout center **only** if the view enough space.

Right now the Input layout are always center and the text go over the image.

In ios i would use constraint priority to do so but it looks like this is not available for constraint layout yet?

What i have right now

[image]

What I want to have is

[image]

Edit

Sorry i should have add the text :)

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/registration_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/logo" />

    <!--To get the focus when page appear-->
    <include layout="@layout/layout_focus_interceptor" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_extra_info"
        style="@style/TextContent"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/input_layout_email"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView" />

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/input_layout_email"
        style="@style/TextInputLayout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_bottom_text_input_layout"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:theme="@style/PreAuthorizationTextTheme"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/input_layout_email_confirmation"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed">

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/etxt_email"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:nextFocusLeft="@id/etxt_email"
            android:nextFocusUp="@id/etxt_email"
            tools:hint="@string/general_email" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/input_layout_email_confirmation"
        style="@style/TextInputLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_bottom_text_input_layout"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_top_text_input_layout"
        android:theme="@style/PreAuthorizationTextTheme"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/input_layout_email">

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/et_email_confirmation"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:nextFocusLeft="@id/etxt_email"
            android:nextFocusUp="@id/etxt_email"
            tools:hint="@string/registration_email_confirmation" />

    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Please share the text part of your layout which will help to get answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know how to do this either! But I was able to come up with something that comes close to what you're looking for.

What I did was create a `Guideline` element fixed at a particular height that caused my views to *seem* vertically centered when they were positioned below it. For different size phones, this will probably be off by a pixel or ten, but it should never be **too** bad.

I then create a `Barrier` that references the guideline and the other view I want to "dodge". And I position my other elements with respect to this barrier.

My XML:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/rect"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:background="#fac"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"/>

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.34"/>

    <android.support.constraint.Barrier
        android:id="@+id/barrier"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:barrierDirection="bottom"
        app:constraint_referenced_ids="rect,guideline"/>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/first"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:background="#caf"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/barrier"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"/>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/second"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:background="#caf"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/first"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

With a short `rect` view the two middle views appear vertically centered, and with a tall `rect` view the two middle views get pushed down:

[image]
[image]

Comment: That works fine ! Hope they will improve this thought.